# Variation in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am using Variation in SharePoint 2013. When I hit my root site i.e
www.abc.com

It goes to the 
www.abc.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Pages/VariationRoot.aspx

And then goes to the
www.abc.com/en-us

I want to remove this glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal Download Strategy, a new feature implemented in SharePoint 2013 to improve the performance. It is activated by default in SharePoint site. It's a technique to use single page "_layouts/15/start.aspx" with URL encoded with following # text.

Minimal Download Strategy will improve the performance of SharePoint site by improving Navigation, Fast Rendering on the client browser. Also reduces the page loading time, because no need to get the duplicate Data from server.

In my case the redirection is happening because of MDS. Disable this by navigating to SharePoint Site Settings Page, Click on Manage Site Features link in Site Actions section -> Deactivate Minimal Download Strategy feature.

http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/386/Remove--_layouts-15-start-aspx---extension-in-SharePoint-URL-address-bar-